# How to store strings greator than 32 length in bigQuery coming from firebase events?

Tags: json, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, bigdata

We are using googles bigQuery for storing events from app side coming through firebase. We wanted to store users fcm or gcm id in bigQuery. But as documented there is a limit of 32 characters while using firebase.

Comment: what document you are referencing?

Comment: the actual documentation from google itself

Comment: can  you provide exact link to the page where you see 32 char limit ?!

Comment: That is actually limitation from firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#public-method-summary

Comment: What exactly problem you are facing? It is totally unclear! Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: question modified.